# My php code transform some caracteres

Tags: php, json, database, url

i got a database with a column with URL. 
The problem with it is that after using my php code, the result given by the page is that my url `http:"//"...` become `http:"\/\/"...`

What's the problem?

Comment: ` http://... become http://...` ..... what?

Comment: You're question isn't really clear but that may depends on me. However, what I really don't understand is that **http://... become http://...** is actually the same??

Comment: Pretty sure `http://...` and `http://...` are the same.  Please provide some examples and then someone might be able to help

Comment: an example : "http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/u1kfgjl.jpg"

Comment: Use the `stripslashes()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those slashes are used to escape the `'` in mysql. After retrieving your data you can use `stripslahes()` to remove them.

```
$str = "A yellow fish swims in earth\'s oceans."
$str = stripslashes($str);
echo $str; // Outputs A yellow fish swims in earth's oceans.
```